# How would I count the number of times a comment meta field's value is in a post's entire comments?

Tags: comments, comment-meta, wp-comment-query

How would I count (and display) the number of times a comment meta field's value is a post's entire comments?

e.g. meta key is "fish" and key value "shark" appears in 5 comments of a post.

Comment: The closest I got was this...
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104782/count-number-of-user-comments-with-a-specific-comment-meta-value

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do a `meta_query` in a [`WP_Comment_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query):

```
$args = array(
    'post_id'    => 'post-id-here',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'fish',
            'value'   => 'shark',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
 );

// Query the comments
$comment_query = new WP_Comment_Query( $args );

// Count the number of comments
$count = count ( $comment_query );
```

The `WP_Comment_query()` accepts a `'post_id'` so you can search withing a specific post's comments.

Comment: How would  I echo that?

Comment: What would the argument be for `post_id`to query the current post comments?

Comment: This is what i have...
`$args = array(
    'post_id'    => $post->ID,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'joinus',
            'value'   => 'Yes',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
 );

// Query the comments
$comment_query = new WP_Comment_Query( $args );

// Count the number of comments
$count = count ( $comment_query );

// echo the number of comments
echo $count;`

Comment: @Pete Are you sure that the `$post->ID` is set? Where and how are you using this code?

Comment: I'm using this in my single.php loop - so I guess I need to find the current post ID

Comment: @Pete Then you should use `get_the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID`, unless you have the `global $post` already set ( not recommended ).

Comment: This isn't counting/echoing the correct number... 
`$args = array(
    'post_id'    => get_the_ID(),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'joinus',
            'value'   => 'Maybe',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
 );

// Query the comments
$comment_query = new WP_Comment_Query( $args );

// Count the number of comments
$count = count ( $comment_query );

echo $count`

Comment: If you want comments that have `shark`, not ONLY are `shark`, you can change the `compare` to `IN`.

Comment: It's only showing 1 at the most